# Clear Navigation Stack mui wpf

Tags: wpf, windows, modern-ui

I'm very new to wpf, right now, I'm using  ModernUI version 1.0.6
I'm searching for a way to clear the navigation history for modernwindow.
Or the way to remove the navigation button out of the modernwindow would also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read the source code of mui, and you will find smoe way to clear.
First you can try reflect the `ModernFrame` class to get `history` field, then you can invoke `Clear()` where you want, and code like this:

```
var frame = view.FindChild<ModernFrame>("ContentFrame");
var field = typeof(ModernFrame).GetField("history", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var history = (Stack<Uri>)field.GetValue(frame);

history.Clear();
```

Second you can find DependencyProperty `KeepContentAlive` in the `ModernFrame` class, this property has a `propertyChangedCallback`, so the navigation history will clear if its value changed. To do this you need to rewrite `ModernWindow`'s style and binding a property with `KeepContentAlive` from vm.